# Knife tool with Maya Settings

Tags: modeling, shortcut, knife-tool

My knife tool (with Maya presets) will not introduce a vertex with LMB, but automatically introduces them on edges when I cross them (despite not pressing LMB). When I switch to Blender presets, the knife tool works as advertised (clicking introduces new vertex, and not automatically when I cross an edge). How can I properly use the knife tool with Maya settings?

Comment: You should be able to customize that part on the Maya settings

Answer (score 2):

To fix this, in file> user preferences > input tab, search for the "knife" tool.

Under "Knife Topology Tool" it should say "Knife Tool Modal Map", click on the drop down arrow next to that and find the "Add Cut" shortcut.

drop down the "Add Cut" arrow and change the option that says "Press" to "Any"

[image]